# R image "increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected" -- but they are

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to use the `image` function in R. It reports "increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected", but I believe that I am providing increasing 'x' and 'y' values.

I suspect that I do not understand what is meant by this term, which I take to mean "Two vectors 'x' and 'y' that form a complete set of coordinate pairs within a space (x, y) and which are sorted first by 'x' and then by 'y', such that x[i] >= x[i+k], {i, k > 0}, and analogously for y."

Here is a minimal example.

Let the following be the contents of `diagnose.txt`:

```
0   0   1
0   1   2
1   0   3
1   1   4
```

I run the following:

```
filename = "diagnose.txt"
t <- read.table(filename, header = FALSE, sep="\t", na.string='NaN')
colnames(t) <- c('x', 'y', 'z')
image(t$x, t$y, t$z)
```

The error message I receive is "increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected"

Surely this cannot mean that I must provide data of the (ill-defined) form:

```
0   0   1
1   1   2
2   2   3
3   3   4
```

What would that even mean? (PS: I tried that, too, just for fun. You get an error messages, as you should, reflecting the ill-formedness of of the coordinate image definition.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MrFlick gives a good description of the underlying issue and how to overcome it when using `image`.

An alternative is to use `lattice`, which is happy with data structured like yours:

```
library(lattice)
d <- read.table(col.names=c('x', 'y', 'z'), 
                text='0   0   1
                      0   1   2
                      1   0   3
                      1   1   4')
```

At its simplest, we can just plot it like this:

```
levelplot(z ~ x + y, data=d)
```

[image: plot1]

If `z` only includes integers, you might want to have a bit more control over the legend:

```
levelplot(z ~ x+y, data=d,
          at=seq(min(d$z, na.rm=T), max(d$z, na.rm=T) + 1) - 0.5,
          colorkey=list(labels=list(
            at=seq(min(d$z, na.rm=T), max(d$z, na.rm=T)), 
            labels=seq(min(d$z, na.rm=T), max(d$z, na.rm=T)))))
```

[image: plot2]

And if you have missing data, these are by default plotted as white cells, so it's a good idea to use a colour ramp that doesn't include white, e.g.:

```
d2 <- read.table(col.names=c('x', 'y', 'z'), 
                 text='0   0   1
                       0   1   2
                       1   0   3
                       1   1   4
                       2   0   2')

levelplot(z ~ x+y, data=d2, col.regions=topo.colors,
          at=seq(min(d$z, na.rm=T), max(d$z, na.rm=T) + 1) - 0.5,
          colorkey=list(labels=list(
            at=seq(min(d$z, na.rm=T), max(d$z, na.rm=T)), 
            labels=seq(min(d$z, na.rm=T), max(d$z, na.rm=T)))))
```

[image: plot3]

Answer (score 7):

When you plot with `image()`, ultimately the `z` parameter needs to be a matrix. The `x` and `y` values then correspond to the `x` values represented by the rows of the matrix and the `y` values correspond to the matrix. If you do not supply these values (you can just pass a matrix to `x` and be done with it), R will assign values from 0 to 1.

So the quick way to turn your data into a matrix is to use the base function `xtabs`. You can run

```
image(xtabs(z~x+y, t))
```

[image]

Note that to use this method, it is important that all values of `x/y` are specified. If there is no combination found for a particular cell, `xtabs` will return 0 which may not be the value you want to associate with that cell.

Because you've already coded with 0/1s it will be just fine. But if you wanted the columns to be at 5 and 6 and the rows to be at 10 and 11, you would do

```
image(5:6, 10:11, xtabs(z~x+y, t))
```

So that's what the `x` and `y` parameters are for, to let you place the matrix of data. I hope that clears things up

Comment: Great use of `xtabs`. The only drawback is that missing data will be given a zero count (i.e. if, for a given level/value of `x`, we are missing `z` at a given `y`, then `xtabs` will return `0`).

Comment: Another way to convert the `x, y, z` data to a matrix appropriate for plotting with `image` (or indeed `levelplot`), that correctly reports `NA`, is: `m <- with(t, tapply(z, list(x, y), I)); levelplot(m); image(m)`.